# Rails 4.2 and gem config broken

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

My OS X ruby dev environment is broken, I don't know why.
I undesrtood that the gem path is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
/Users/muqaddar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rails' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/muqaddar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598:/Users/muqaddar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Here is my config with gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 598) [x86_64-darwin14.1.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/muqaddar/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598
     - /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin
     - /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/bin
     - /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin
     - /usr/local/mysql/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /Users/muqaddar/.rvm/bin
```

I tried many things, reading lots of threads.
- reinstall rvm
- remove .vendor/bundle
- bundle install
...etc

I think the gems are not installed in the right directory. How to change that depending my rvm config ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try and follow these steps if you are using a mac: http://www.installrails.com/

Note that when installing a new gem, you first have to add it to the Gemfile inside your editor. For example: gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
After doing this navigate to your folder using terminal and type: "bundle install". This will install your added gems.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I didn't know. However I'm not new to rails. I always did like this when I install my gems. I don't know what is the problem and why my config breaks suddenly.